# SASS: Add pseudo-class to grandparent ampersand

Tags: sass

This SASS code...

```
@mixin test
{
  @at-root #{selector-replace(&, '.class1', '.class1:nth-child(odd)')}
  {
    color:red;
  }
}

.class1
{
  .class2
  {
     @include test;
  }
}
```

...compiles to:

```
.class1:nth-child(odd) .class2
{
  color: red;
}
```

Is this possible when not using selector-replace (because I don't know how class1 is called)?

I just want to add a nth-child selector to the grandparent.

I am only allowed to change the mixin, not the original code.

Comment: The `mixin` must be called inside `.class2`?

Comment: Yes. class2 is a button that has a specific style provided by the mixin. And it should be red on every second class1-item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this will do the trick:

```
@mixin test
{

  // Find the first selector
  $parent : nth(nth(&, 1), 1);

  // Defines a list for the rest of the selectors
  $rest : ();

  // For each selector of &, starting from the second
  @for $i from 2 through length(nth(&, 1)) {

    // Adds the selector to the list of the "rest of the selectors"
    $rest: append($rest, nth(nth(&, 1), $i));

  }

  // Adds the selector at root
  @at-root #{$parent}:nth-child(odd) #{$rest} {
    color: red;
  }

}

.class1
{
  .class2
  {
    @include test;
  }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.class1:nth-child(odd) .class2 {
  color: red;
}
```

Hope it helps!